# Similarities and differences: 'in + VERBing' vs 'VERBing' alone

Tags: differences, prepositions, legalese, ing, prepositional-objects

Source: p 145, Frederick Schauer’s *Thinking Like a Lawyer*

> **In being** an empirical response to
>   an empirical claim, this explanation engages Realism on its own terms,
>   and so little can be said here other than that if Realism is empirically correct
>   for much of law, then the fact that Realism may now be substantially
>   disregarded is surprising and disturbing.

1. Is there a name for the structure *in* + gerund? I tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+being%22+vs+being&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Tt7MU4S4DNCVkgWY54CQDA) which revealed nothing.
2. What are the similarities and differences between the version with the preposition (eg **in being**) and the version without it (eg **being**)?

Comment: 'In being' can be replaced by 'in that it is ...', which indicates the sense of 'in' here. The preposition is usually dropped from the former.

Comment: @tchrist I've fixed the terminological mixup (though some would argue it doesn't matter what you call it). I don't see how the second question is too broad—it's quite specific to me.

Answer (score 1):

> **In being** an empirical response to an empirical claim, this explanation engages Realism on its own terms, and so little can be said here other than that if Realism is empirically correct for much of law, then the fact that Realism may now be substantially disregarded is surprising and disturbing.

Could be rewritten as:

> This explanation -- because it is an empirical response to an empirical claim -- engages Realism on its own terms, and so little can be said here other than that if Realism is empirically correct for much of law, then the fact that Realism may now be substantially disregarded is surprising and disturbing.

The rationale for using the phrase **in being** is to describe that it is *within* the state of being that the subject is thusly manifested and/or described.

To replace **in being** with simply **being** would more ambiguously suggest that the subject only currently exists (is / does be) as such, and not the more precise notion that is actually *within* such an existence is this state, condition, and/or circumstance so set forth.

The author is not just making a statement **about** "this explanation", he is specifically detailing the reasoning for **how** "the explanation" does "engage[] Realism". It does so "**in being** an empirical response to an empirical claim".

For example:

> **In dancing** I have come to find the meaning of true joy.

That is not to merely suggest that while I'm currently dancing I have currently discovered the meaning of true joy, but to more universally state that it is within the general specificity of engaging in the act of dancing that I have come to generally and consistently discover the meaning of true joy.

It has the leanings of a philosophical statement of the nature of the subject within the state, not so much the actionable/actioned state of the gerund with respect to the subject.

Comment: I don't think your dancing example holds up; that's just a transposed version of “I have found my joy in dancing”, where the structure is _find [object] in/at/on [location]_, no different from “In the hallway I found her”.

Comment: Your example is a fundamentally different statement than my example with "in dancing". To make your hallway example match my dancing example it would have to be: "In being in the hallway, I was able to find her.". They are statements on the state of the verb as actionable by the subject.

Answer (score 0):

"in + gerund" does not occur so often.
It can have several uses:

1 Mostly it is the same as on + gerund (temporal):

On entering his room he saw at once that someone had been in his room.

2 It can mean when or temporal as + clause:

In trying to escape ...

3 It can mean by doing as in:

In doing so she made an enemy.

And you will find that beside these three main uses there can be found slightly different uses as in:

And there will be some who will follow you in drawing sword.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition here serves the same purpose as elsewhere and does not in any way affect the implication/ connotation of the verbal gerund. I see this Q as a NARQ/GR.